# Is it possible to retrieve a user's homepage URL from the browser with JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, browser

Just so it's clear: I don't want to reset their homepage.  I just want to pull the URL of their homepage and load content from it as part of an application demo.

So far my research hasn't turned up anything, is retrieving a user's homepage possible with JavaScript?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, that would be a significant privacy violation. If browsers allowed you to access this data, you could potentially detect the user's e-mail provider, bank of choice, or company intranet if they had it set as their home page.

Answer (score 1):

Not that I know of.

That'd be a pretty major security hole if you could.

Answer (score 1):

No. That would be a horrendous security problem.  I don't want A.N. Other web developer finding out arbitrary browser settings.  That's private, and browsers correctly respect that.

Answer (score 0):

If it did then the browser maker needs to have a word with it's developers.